# Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have facing a problem while i am trying to restore the Data base in sqlserver 2012 .

My project configuration :

**ASP.Net core 2.0, 
Vs2017 Preview2,
c#**

i have installed **Microsoft.SqlServer.Scripting** using nuget package , then i tried to restore data base  using below code

```
try
{
    string DatabaseName = "TestDB";
    String ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog= " + DatabaseName + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    // Error on the line below
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection conn = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
    Server srv = new Server(conn);
    Console.WriteLine(srv.Information.Version);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string exepe = ex.Message.ToString();
}
```

Error is :

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlContext' from
>   assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Did i miss anything? can you please any body help me out this .

Comment: It's likely not there (neither on [packagesearch](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) nor on github [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src)) for .NET Core and you have to target .NET Framework instead

Comment: Hello Tseng thanks for your reply , yeah i tried .Net Framework also i gives same error .  I tried with windows application there  it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. I solved it by referencing [Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects).