# How send SQL request with "go" in C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have some SQL request:

```
go
Update dbo.Parameter set ValueAsStr = '{
 "CreateDepoUrl": "https://sandbox.sg...../",
 "CheckDepoStatusUrl": "https://sandbox.sg..../",
 "CreatePayoutUrl": "https://sandbox.sg....../",
 "CheckPayoutStatusUrl": "https://sandbox.sg..../",
 "PayoutTerminalIds": {
....
go
```

If I send this request in SSMS all is alright 
My method for send SQL request from C# code:

```
public static void SendToMainSqlRequest(MainDbContext mainDbContext, string queryString)
{

    using (var conn = mainDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();

        var command = mainDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = queryString;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        int number = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("count of updates: {0}", number);
        
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

When I send request in C# code I get an exception:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

If I delete "dbo." in the SQL request I get an exception:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Table and field names are correct. Without typos. 
How I can solve this problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: "GO" is not a SQL command, it's a delimiter that is only known by SSMS. So you will need to filter that out

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL operator; they should not be in your SQL when writing it in C#. `GO` is a batch separate that is recognised by IDEs, such as SSMS, SQLCMD, ADS, DBeaver, etc, etc.

Comment: related: [GO statements blowing up sql execution in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18596876/121309)

Comment: Read the script line-by-line. If "GO" was read, execute the statements you collected until now, then continue reading via same logic until end. That is what SSMS does.

Comment: Simply filtering out "GO" wont be good everywhere. There are statements which should be the first ones in a batch, so after a "GO" it is okay but if "GO" was filtered out and the statement becomes a middle one in the batch it wont work.

Comment: Cannot debug a fragment of sql code that is, in turn, executed by incomplete c# code. Post a complete example.

Comment: use environmet.newline

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL Server Management Objects library to execute SQL commands with GO statements. We use this internally for executing database migration scripts to update our database schema.

[Here's the library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects).

And some sample code demonstrating how to use it:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));

    //this is to get script output (if you have any)
    server.ConnectionContext.ServerMessage += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Error.Message);
    };

    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("some SQL with GO statements");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the code bellow to do this :

```
...
var lines = GoSplitter.Split(queryString);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    command.CommandText = line;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    int number = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // process number if needed
}
...
```

The class GoSplitter *(sorry comments are in french)*:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DatabaseAndLogLibrary.DataBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Coupe un texte SQL en fonction des GO
    /// Prend en compte les Go dans les chaines ou les commentaires SQL qui eux doivent être ignorés
    /// Retire aussi les instruction SQL : USE
    /// </summary>
    internal class GoSplitter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Pour détection des instruction USE
        /// </summary>
        private static Regex regUse = new Regex(@"^\s*USE\s");

        /// <summary>
        /// Renvoie la liste des instructions SQL séparé en fonction des GO dans le script d'origine
        /// Prend en compte les Go dans les chaines ou les commentaires SQL qui eux doivent être ignorés
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileContent"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEnumerable<string> Split(string fileContent)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileContent))
            {
                yield break;
            }

            string res;
            var currentState = EState.Normal;
            List<Marker> markers = LoadMarker(fileContent).OrderBy(x => x.Index).ToList();

            int index0 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < markers.Count; i++)
            {
                switch (currentState)
                {
                    case EState.Normal:
                        switch (markers[i].Event)
                        {
                            case EMarker.Go:
                                res = fileContent.Substring(index0, markers[i].Index - index0).Trim();
                                res = ReplaceUse(res);
                                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res))
                                {
                                    yield return res;
                                }

                                index0 = markers[i].Index + 2;  // 2 lettres dans go
                                break;
                            case EMarker.Quote:
                                currentState = EState.InText;
                                break;
                            case EMarker.Comment:
                                currentState = EState.InComment;
                                break;
                        }

                        break;
                    case EState.InText:
                        if (markers[i].Event == EMarker.Quote)
                        {
                            currentState = EState.Normal;
                        }

                        break;
                    case EState.InComment:
                        if (markers[i].Event == EMarker.EndComment)
                        {
                            currentState = EState.Normal;
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

            res = fileContent.Substring(index0, fileContent.Length - index0).Trim();
            res = ReplaceUse(res);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res))
            {
                yield return res;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Charge les points clés du script
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileContent"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static  IEnumerable<Marker> LoadMarker(string fileContent)
        {
            var regGo = new Regex(@"\bgo\b", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            foreach(var m in  regGo.Matches(fileContent).Where(x => x.Success).Select(x => new Marker() { Index = x.Index, Event = EMarker.Go }))
            {
                yield return m;
            }

            var regQuote = new Regex(@"'", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (var m in regQuote.Matches(fileContent).Where(x => x.Success).Select(x => new Marker() { Index = x.Index, Event = EMarker.Quote }))
            {
                yield return m;
            }

            var regComment1 = new Regex(@"-(-)+[\s\S]*?$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match m in regComment1.Matches(fileContent).Where(x => x.Success))
            {
                yield return new Marker() { Index = m.Index, Event = EMarker.Comment };
                yield return new Marker() { Index = m.Index + m.Length, Event = EMarker.EndComment };
            }

            var regComment2 = new Regex(@"/\*[\s\S]*?\*/", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match m in regComment2.Matches(fileContent).Where(x => x.Success))
            {
                yield return new Marker() { Index = m.Index, Event = EMarker.Comment };
                yield return new Marker() { Index = m.Index + m.Length, Event = EMarker.EndComment };
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Remplace les instructions using
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sqlLine"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string ReplaceUse(string sqlLine)
            => regUse.Replace(sqlLine, string.Empty); // .Replace("USE", "---");

        [DebuggerDisplay("{Index} - {Event}")]
        private class Marker
        {
            public int Index {get; set;}
            public EMarker Event { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// les types de détection qui aggissent sur l'automate
        /// </summary>
        private enum EMarker
        {
            Go,
            Quote,
            Comment,
            EndComment
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Les états de l'automate
        /// </summary>
        private enum EState
        {
            Normal,
            InComment,
            InText
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!